# Why does my Heroku site display 'Unauthorised' on Edge but not Chrome?

Tags: heroku

When attempting to access a Heroku site via Edge, the user receives an "Unauthorised" message on the page, but through Chrome there is no issue. Has anyone else seen this?

Have tried clearing cache, using InPrivate, but the result is still the same.

Comment: Have you checked cookie settings? Chrome and Edge come with different defaults that can come with different results in certain cases.